# Magento product import coruption on duplicated products

Tags: magento, import, magento-1.7

The following steps will reproduce product data corruption on a fresh install of the latest Magento with no sample data:

1. Create a new product and enter data for: Name, Description, Short Description, SKU, Weight, Status, Visibility, Price and Tax class
2. Save the product
3. Edit the product you just created and duplicate it
4. Edit the duplicated product and fill in the SKU which is missing
5. Save the duplicate product
6. Export all product data via System >> Import/Export >> Export
7. Import the CSV that you’ve just exported via System >> Import/Export >> Export and choose “Replace Existing Complex Data”

Now when you go to “Manage products” you will see both the original product and the duplicate product shown, but the duplicated product will not have a price shown. If you edit both products you will find that the original product is exactly as it should be but all fields apart from the SKU are empty for the duplicated product. Its interesting to note that the name of the duplicated product is shown in the “Manage products” list, but not in the actual product itself.

How do I import this data without this corruption happening?

Should I file a bug report

Comment: Are you saying the 2 products have the same SKU?

Comment: Nope, at step 4 add a different SKU.

Comment: How much of the data makes it into the database? You mentioned that the product name appears in the "Manage products" list, so perhaps there's more info around the place? Also, does the duplicated product show up in the front-end of the website?

Comment: Using phpmyadmin I've found the changes after the data is imported. In the catalog_product_entity_text, there are two entries for each product and the attribute_id for one entry of each product is incremented by one. Then in the table catalog_product_entity_decimal, the weight and price of the cloned product has been set to NULL.

Comment: So do the text attributes for the products have correct non-NULL values?

Comment: Yes, they have the correct non null values.

Comment: Might be best to put through a bug report if it's consistently happening with the latest version of Magento.